# Era taking longer than expected on Westend?

Tags: polkadot, era, westend

I'm testing with Westend network and it seems like the current era hasn't change for almost 4 days when it's supposed to change every 6h - is that normal / to be expected? And if that's normal how this affects the un-bonding periods since they expressed in "eras"?

Attaching a screenshot below:

[image: westend era longer than normal]

Comment: Is this for Westend or are you running Westend locally?

Comment: That's for public Westend, you can see that on official polkadot.js app when you go to Network -> Staking -> Overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm just checked it now and looks fine to me:

[image]

Network > Staking > Overview

[image]

Consider reloading.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't perfectly clear - my screenshot was from the Network -> Staking tab. And not it still shows the same era, almost 5 days now.

Comment: Updated my screenshots. Looks fine to me. Try connecting to a Parity node and see if there is a difference.

Comment: hmm... yeah it looks OK now for me too - not sure what happened as I was trying with incognito mode & different nodes earlier to rule out any caching issues... thanks for your help :)

Comment: We are consistently seeing wrong era info for Westend at our side too, connecting to every node and in several computers.  I created an issue for polkadot-js: https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/issues/7607